# Setting RGB color of a certain pixel in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an image, and i want to set color of one and only one specific pixel to an rgb value.

first: How to choose a pixel: `pixelname = [5,6] //as the pixel on the fifth column third row`

Second: How to set its color: `pixelname.setrgb(30,20,60) //30,20,60 are rgb colors`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the bitmap containing the pixel you want to change and then change color using `bitmap.setPixel(X, Y, Color)`.

Comment: how to choose the certain pixel?

Comment: bitmap.getPixel(X, Y) and it will return the Color of the pixel

Comment: Note, if you use this method for setting a pixel you might need to add Bitmap newBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
newBitmap.setHasAlpha(true); in order to do to if your bitmap is not editable/immutable.